# NameError trying to access Connection variable in Channel

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I have a Connection that sets a `current_user` variable:

```
class MyConnection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
  identified_by :current_user

  def connect
    # snip - work to authenticate the user    
    self.current_user = user
  end
end
```

According to the docs, this should make the variable `current_user` available to the corresponding channel. [The docs say](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/Channel/Base.html):

> Also note that in this example, current_user is available because it was marked as an identifying attribute on the connection. All such identifiers will automatically create a delegation method of the same name on the channel instance.

However, when I try to access `current_user` in `MyChannel`:

```
class MyChannel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
  def subscribed
    subscription_name = "my_channel#{current_user.id}"
    stream_from subscription_name
  end
end
```

I get a `NameError`:

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<MyChannel:0x00000000deadbeef>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here's another example that makes it look like my code should work. The RSpec docs on testing a channel show stubbing a `user_id` value on the corresponding connection This strongly suggests that the `user_id` value from the connection (which has presumably been set up accordingly) is normally available to the channel. https://relishapp.com/palkan/action-cable-testing/docs